# Get value from string formed as URL in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, url, string

Ok, I have a string of the form

```
string temp = "http://www.example.com?file=666111&submitter=Betty&origin=Office&telNo=05555";
```

what I need to do is extract the value of the file variable in order to use it. If this was the referrer url I could've done `Request.QueryString` and got it but the problem is that I have it as a string variable.

I could try to do substring and get the value but I was hoping there was a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you can use the [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) method. It returns a `NameValueCollection` with all parameters.